# irrational, proving or finding counterexapmle

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, real-numbers

Prove or find a counterexample: For all real numbers x and y it holds that
x + y is irrational if, and only if, both x and y are irrational.

Can anyone give me a hint just about how to start cause i cannot come up on how and where to start.

Do I have to look for 2 irrational numbers and add then , iff, both have to be irrational and how do i come up with a counterexample or a prove?
i need help